# how to center links with image links floating right next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, navbar

hello i would like to have the textlinks of my navbar center at the top of my page but they´re not centered properly because i have 3 imagelinks floating to the right in the same navbar.

also just fyi, i have both , the css and the js in seperate files and they´re linked to my html.

```js
document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML =
"<p>&copy;  " + new Date().getFullYear() + " SITE. All rights reserved.</p>";

document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +
"<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder2</a></li>" +
"<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder3</a></li>" +
"<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder4</a></li>" +
"<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder5</a></li>" +
"<li><a class='social' href='instagram.html'><span class='socialtrans'></span><img src='graphics/Instagram_App_Large_May2016_200.png' alt='instagram'></a></li>" +
"<li><a class='social' href='youtube.html'><span class='socialtrans'></span><img src='graphics/YouTube-logo-full_color.png' alt='youtube'></a></li>" +
"<li><a class='social' href='soundloud.html'><span class='socialtrans'></span><img src='graphics/soundcloud-icon.png' alt='soundcloud'></a></li>"
"</ul>";

function setActive() {
aObj = document.getElementById('nav01').getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
  aObj[i].className='active';
}
}
}

window.onload = setActive;

window.onscroll = function() {addnavbg()};

function addnavbg() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
    document.getElementById('menu').className = 'navbg';
} else {
    document.getElementById('menu').className = '';
}
}
```

```css
/* website style */

body {
font-size: 16px;
background-color: #ffffff; 
color: #000000;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
height:auto;
width:100%;
margin-top:60px;
}

#main {
max-width:1024px;
margin:0 auto;
}

footer {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

/* license info */

img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

/* navigation */

ul#menu {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
transition:background-color 0.2s linear;
}

.navscrolldown {background-color:#424242;}

ul#menu li {display:inline;}

ul#menu li a {
background-color:transparent;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
    display:inline-block;
padding: 10px 16px;
transition:color 0.2s;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color:transparent;
font-weight: bold;
color:#FF0000;
}

ul#menu a.regular:link {padding-top:15px;}

ul#menu li a.active {color:#ff0000;}

/* social media links */

ul#menu a.social:link {
border:0;
height:30px;
width:30px;
float:right;
}

ul#menu a.social.link:hover {display:inline-block;}

.socialtrans {
position:absolute;
width:30px;
height:30px;
float:right;
opacity:1;
transition:opacity 0.2s;
}

.socialtrans:hover {
background-color:#ffffff;
opacity:0.7;
}

/* iframe */

iframe#mfs_html5 {
width:100%;
height:510px;
border:0;
overflow:hidden;
}

document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML="<ul id='menu'>" +"<li><a href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +"<li><a href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +"<li><a href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +"<li><a href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +"<li><a href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +"<li><a class='social' href='Placeholder1.html' ><span class='hvr'></span><img src

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="llorem ipsum" />
<meta name="keywords" content="llorem ipsum" />
<title>Placeholder1</title>
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav id="nav01"></nav>

<div id="main">

<div id="header"><img src="graphics/header.jpg" alt="header"></div>

<iframe id="mfs_html5" src="Placeholder1"></iframe>

<div id="info"><img src="graphics/Placeholder1.png" alt="Placeholder1"></div>

</div>

<footer id="foot01"></footer>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<div id="nav01"></div>
```

Comment: i have added the html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `display:table;` and setting the most outer layer of the navigation element to `margin: 0 auto;` in this case that would be `#nav01`.

```
/* navigation */

#nav01{
 display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
 margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#menu {
 margin:0 auto;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li{
 float:left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pg4w30yv/

Comment: i tried to implement it into my css but i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: yes i did and it works fine in jfiddle but if i try to put your code into my css it doenst work. i updated the css code maybe you can take another look at it because i have changed it since ive posted this question.